# What accounts for the difference in probability of coin toss experiment before experiment vs after start of experiment?

Tags: probability, statistics

I apologize in advance because I'm guessing this question has been asked a thousand different ways. But if someone can explain it to me in the following terms, I'd much appreciate it.

Probability of flipping coin heads once:

$P(1)=0.5$

Probability of flipping coin 2 times and getting heads both times:

$P(2) = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25$

This rule can be generalized for `n` independent events of equal probability like so, correct?

$P(n) = P(1)^n$

So, if I plan to flip the coin twice, then probability of flipping tails at least once is 1 - chance of flipping heads both times:

$1 - P(2) = 1 - 0.25 = 0.75$

If that's valid, then before I start flipping, I have a 75% chance I'll flip tails at least once if I flip the coin exactly twice?

So, I flip the coin once and get Heads. Now I have only 50% chance that I'll get Tails.

What accounts for the difference of 75% probability before vs 50% after?

Does the new information I have about the new state of my coin toss experiment change the probability? Or is my logic flawed somewhere?

If the new information changes things, then was the first calculated probability of 75% ever useful? It feels like the probability will change from 75% to something different after the start of the experiment no matter what.

Comment: The four outcomes of flipping a coin twice are HH, HT, TT, and TH. Once you have flipped once and gotten H, your two flips must be either HT or HH, thus the probability of "at lease one tail" is 50%. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Of course new information changes your assessment of the probabilities.  If you flip the coin  twice and get $HH$ the probability that you will get at least one Tails in those two rolls has dropped to $0$.  Your calculation of the probability reflects the available information.  If that information changes, so will your calculation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  For more on this question, see [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

Comment: Thanks @lulu. If we know that new information will always change the original assessment, then isn't that original assesment fundamentally always incorrect? In this example, we know without a doubt, even beforehand, that after the first flip, our assessment of 75% will be invalid. So how can 75% probability ever be a legitimate assessment?

Comment: the two assessments refer to different situations.  Saying that $75\%$ of the time you'll get at least one $T$ on two tosses of a coin is true.  Saying that, having gotten an $H$ on the first toss, your probability drops to $50\%$ is also true.  Different answers for different situations.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to think of a sample space.  Suppose you have people with initials $\{AB,AC,AD,XB,XC\}$.  The probability that a randomly selected person from that same has last initial $D$ is $\frac 15$.  If, however, I tell you that the randomly selected person has first initial $X$ then that probability drops to $0$.  Again, probabilities must be reassessed in light of changing information.

Comment: @lulu fair enough, that makes sense that I'm confusing the answers for 2 totally separate situations. But, even in your example, we all know without a doubt before you even select a person that the 1/5 probability will change after you select the first person. I think that's the source of my unease. Why isn't the knowledge of what absolutely will happen in the future not considered in the original assessment? Could it be possible to maybe come up with some sort of recursively forward looking definition to make a better initial assessment?

Comment: At the start you consider all the possible branches.  Choosing someone with first initial $X$ drops the probability to $0$, while drawing someone with first initial $A$ increases it to $\frac 13$.  At the start, both branches are possible.   Even with the coin toss, you know from the start that the first toss will change your estimate.  Getting an $H$ will cause you to drop down to $\frac 12$ while getting a $T$ will cause you to jump to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure to what extent your question is a philosophical one about what we mean by probabilities. If so, perhaps you should try to sharpen it in light of the exchanges in the comments.

To the extent that it’s a mathematical question in a narrower sense, we can look at how we might go about implementing your idea of “looking forward to make a better initial assessment”.

So, you’re right to say that we already know before the first coin flip that there will be different probabilities after the coin flip. (I’m deliberately not saying “the probabilities will change” because that would seem to feed into your misconception that these are somehow the same probabilities, just with different values, and hence the initial values were somehow “invalid”.) And we know not only *that* there will be different probabilities, but also what they can turn out to be, and with what probability that will happen: With probability $\frac12$ the first coin flip will be heads and then the probability to get at least one tails will be $\frac12$, and with probability $\frac12$ the first coin flip will be tails and then the probability to get at least one tails will be $1$.

So let’s try to use that to “look forward to make a better initial assessment”. What is the expected value of this probability? It’s $\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot1=\frac34$! So it turns out that there’s no improvement to be made here – the probability *before* the first flip of obtaining at least one flip is the expected value of the probability *after* the first flip of obtaining at least one flip. We’ll have more information after the first flip, when we know its result, but as long as we don’t, the best we can do is take the expected value, and that’s already what we’re doing.

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks to your answer and @lulu's comments, I think I see now that it is indeed possible to look forward at all the possible outcomes and use that information to calculate the starting probability. I guess that's the best we can possibly do without looking into the future ;-)